# Haskell Program Crashes with GUI but not CLI

Tags: haskell, gtk, glade

I'm trying to build a Haskell program (Hets) with Fedora 18. The program compiles fine and it has two options at startup: with GUI or with CLI. If I start it with the CLI then it works fine. If I try to start it with the GUI, I get a white sqaure on screen and then it crashes with this error in the console:

```
hets: fd:10: hFlush: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
```

I've built and run the same program on Ubuntu 13.04 so I don't think it's the source code but possibly a library issue on Fedora 18.

Could someone suggest why this might happen?

TIA,
Keith

**Update:** I've copied the binary over from Ubuntu (where it works) to Fedora and I get the same error message.

Comment: Could you give a link to this “hets” program please?

Comment: Hi Dave, the link to the homepage is: http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/forschung/formal_methods/CoFI/hets/index_e.htm but you can check it out from SVN using: svn co https://svn-agbkb.informatik.uni-bremen.de/Hets/trunk Hets

Comment: Right, so the gui libraries it seems to be using are `gtk` and `glade`. [Link to cabal file](https://svn-agbkb.informatik.uni-bremen.de/Hets/trunk/Hets.cabal).

Comment: I installed those using cabal install gtk glade

Comment: Did you also install gtk and glade themselves?

Comment: Do you mean did I run: yum install glade gtk2? If so, yes I have those installed and gtk3.